# Spyder is unable to show the variable you are trying to view

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am using Spyder 4.1.5 with Python 3.8.5 with Anaconda

When trying to show the content of a variable in Spyder i get the following error

> Spyder is unable to show the variable you are trying to view because the module spydercustomize was not found in your Spyder environment. Please install this package in your Spyder environment.

A simple `pip install spydercustomize` does not work

I don't even know why it is missing. I think the problem occured the first time when I tried to update Spyder. A reinstallation of Anaconda didn't help either.

My Google skills were not good enough to find any solution. I only find problems where variables don't show in the variable explorer. But that is not my problem.

Btw, built in classes like lists or dicts can be displayed, custom classes can't.

I appreciate your help!

**EDIT**

After updating to Spyder 4.2.0 I got the following error:

> Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the
> console.
>
> The error message was:
>  An error occured, see the console.
>
> Note: Please don't report this problem on Github, there's nothing to
> do about it.

Console is empty

Answer (score 0):

Looks like spydercustomize is part of a package called spyder-kernels. Maybe try:

```sh
$ pip install spyder spyder-kernels --upgrade
```

Comment: After updating the kernel i got an depencies error 
(jedi = 0.17.1: 0.17.2 (NOK).
After reinstalling jedi, i still get the same error with spydercustomize

Comment: @Vyndell When you reinstalled jedi, did it install 0.17.2? If I open a python terminal and run "import jedi; help(jedi);" I see 0.17.2. For spyder, I have 4.2.1. For spyder_kernels, I have 1.10.1. Do you have the same versions?

Comment: I didn't check for the version. I switched to PyCharm instead and i figured: PyCharm >> Spyder (even with the working variable explorer)